# Validity of RSI claims for Emacs users

Tags: evil, spacemacs

If this is not a relevant place to post this, please let me know.

My common workflow is Vim+Tmux. Mostly i do Clojure coding. Just yesterday i've downloaded and tried Spacemacs, out of curiosity.

One of Spacemacs's claims is that by using modal editing in Evil mode, it minimizes RSI risk (albeit on the Spacemacs home page it is said that there is no proven connection between Emacs key bindings and RSI). I realized though, that heavy use of Vim/Tmux also relies on the use of modifier keys, which most often in my case are Control-key combinations (navigating between Vim windows and Tmux prefix - `Ctrl-S` in my case).

So i thought that here is the best place to ask about RSI caused by heavy use of modifier keys (Emacs seems to be associated with it, namely the 'Emacs pinky' myth). Is it something scientifically proven? Were there any studies?

If there does exist a correlation, then does e.g. remapping `CapsLock` to `Ctrl` help?

P. S. I do have `CapsLock` mapped to `Ctrl`. Moreover, in Vim i've remapped `Esc` to `Tab`, which is similarly convenient. And it more closely resembles original keyboard [layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi#/media/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg) Bill Joy used when creating Vi. Maybe it was also used by Emacs users back then?

Comment: I did not find any study on this but I have yet to find a list of Vim users with RSI syndromes. Whereas a list of _famous_ Emacs users with RSI is easily found on the web (like on wikipedia, EDIT: actually there is no such list on the emacs english page of Wikipedia).

Comment: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17492/does-emacs-cause-emacs-pinky

Comment: Unless someone truly can come up with a rigorous scientific study, which I doubt, this should be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Best method I know of to protect your pinky is to combine Space with Control, for Linux there is Xcape for others OSs I don't know. Capslock mapped to Ctrl continues stressing your pinky.

Comment: There's only one paper I'm aware of that compares Vim to Emacs in a more or less scientific way: http://mjambon.github.io/vim-vs-emacs/ I have some vague memory of an anecdote which made reference to some paper allegedly published in the late 70s which ruled that Vim is better in this regard, but I couldn't find even the anecdote itself. PS. I use Kinesis keyboard, all my modifier keys are under thumbs.

Comment: In my opinion, this question is just a reference request and emacs-related, so seems to be fine for this site.

Comment: @wvxw - thanks for the link! Alas, it seems that the referenced paper is a pseudo-scientific one. Sentences of the kind _"Vim, in contrast, is a programming language...", _"GNU Emacs is a commercial product licensed by the Free Software Foundation."_, _"We therefore suggest that leading scientific journals should consider accepting submissions in Vim only if this is justified by the level of mathematics presented in the paper"_ led me to think so for obvious reasons (they are just funny).

Comment: The link sent by wvxvw seems to be rather a joke.

Comment: @Drew if the question is about existence of studies about RSI then it should not be closed. Maybe someone should post an answer that for now there is no such studies so we can keep the answer opened.